# Tiny House on a 8x 27 5th wheel RV frame.20 ft main frame 7 ft on 5th wheel top frame

Tags: framing

Rv is gone  100%  only frame and dual wheels  left. I'm wanting to build the walls and rafters from a metal material. size or grade which metal? no welding..  thought it better for weight.  will not be a traveling home.  hope to only have to move once to own land

Comment: Move & build or build & move? Even for **one** move, it has to hold up to road transit stresses. "Best" is a subjective thing and will likely end up closed as off-topic - you may want to [edit] the question to something that's less opinion based. Consider taking the [tour] to see how this site works.

Comment: Need some clarity in your question. What do you need help with? Give us details.

Comment: Was the frame exposed to a fire?

Comment: i dont know what happened to rv. bought just frame

Comment: help is proper metal stud grade. to build with metal.  ty

Comment: can build after move

Comment: @Toni If you use more words, **I.E**. *Do not leave out words*, It will be easier to under what you are talking about. Plus you will not sound like Frankenstein's monster.